# Why do these two functions have different graph?

Tags: functions, education

Given `g(x+1)=x^3`, `f(x) = (x-1)^3`. Why do they have different graphs? In other words, for function `g`, when `x=0`, its result is `0`, instead for function `f`, its value is `-1`, and when `x=1`,`g(x+1)`'s result is `1` while `f(x)`'s result is 0, and so forth, which obviously they will have different graphs. However, In my mind, the function `g(x+1)` is just a variant of `f(x)`. So, I wonder whether the graph of `g(x+1)` should be the same as `f(x)` or not.

Comment: The functions are the same. The graphs are the same. When you substitute $x=0$ you get $g(1) = 0$ and $f(0) = -1$. This is not a contradiction.

Comment: @M.Wind However, the graph of a function is described by both `x`  and the result, obviously when `x=0`, `g` has a different result from `f`, as you said.

Comment: `g` is not a function of $x$.

Comment: $g(1) = 0$  means that the graph of $g$ has a point $P$ with coordinates $(1, 0)$. This is exactly the same if you substitute $x=1$ into $f$.

Comment: @M.Wind In other words, how is the graph of a function built? Is it built with the set of the value of `x` and the result of the function, or is built with the set of the inputted value and the result of the function? Your answers seem to imply the latter, that is `g(1)` and `f(1)` where `(1,0)` is the element of the graph.

Comment: The graph is based on a list of $x$ values as inputs and the associated $y$ values which are calculated with $f$ or $g$. If you make such a tabel, you will see that there is no difference between $f$ and $g$.

Comment: Can you clarify what functions you are trying to graph? Firstly $y=f(x)$, and which of the following: $y=g(x)$ or $y=g(x+1)$?

Comment: @M.Wind What does " values as inputs" mean here? Is it the value of `x`, or the value you input, specifically, for example, `g(1)`, does the `x values as inputs` means `1` or `0` that is calculated by `x+1 = 1`?

Comment: @peterwhy the graph of `y = g(x+1)`.

Answer (score 0):

The OP presents the function $g$ in an unusual form by giving it the argument $x+1$, whereas the argument $x$ is standard in mathematics. Still, in my opinion this choice is quite acceptable. Unfortunately the OP then gets confused on how to plot the graphs of $f$ and $g$.

Let us choose some $x$ values and evaluate $f$ and $g$:

$$x=0;  \space g(1)=0; \space f(0) = -1$$
$$x=1; \space g(2) = 1; \space f(1) = 0$$
$$x = 2; \space g(3) = 8; \space f(2)=1$$
$$x = 3; \space g(4) = 27; \space f(3)=8$$

We verify that $g(1)=f(1) = 0$, $g(2) = f(2)=1$, $g(3) = f(3)=8$. Therefore the functions are the same and so are there graphs.

Comment: I'm confused about which pair values build the graph of a function. Specifically, is it the value of the variable `x` and the result of the function, or the input value and the result of the function? The former means `(x =0, g(1)=0)` build the graph of `g` while `(x = 0, f(0)=-1)` build the graph of `f`. Instead, the latter means `1, g(1)` build the graph of `g` while `(1,f(1))` build the graph of `f`.

Comment: Why I have this confusion is that, in my mind, the coordinate is established by the `x` axis and the `y` axis. By this logic, the graph in the coordinate should be built up by the value of the variable `x` and the result of `y`.

Comment: You choose $x=0$ as input and get the point $P = (1,0)$ on the graph of $g$. That is the consequence of your own (slightly odd) choice of representing the function $g$.

Comment: @xmh0511 You two might be asking and answering two different questions. $y=g(x)$ and $y=f(x)$ have the same graph. The OP was sometimes conflicting that they asked for both "the graph of `y = g(x+1)`" and "the graph of `g`" in different comments.

Comment: However, the coordinate has an `x` axis and a `y` axis, isn't the value of the `x` axis should be the value of the variable `x`? That is, choose `x = 0`, the point should be `(0, 0)` for `g`?

Comment: @peterwhy So, `y = f(x)` and `y = g(x+1)` have different graphs, right? `y = f(t)` and `y = g(t)` should have the same graphs.

Comment: @xmh0511 Right, $y=f(x)=(x-1)^3$ and $y=g(x+1)=x^3$ have different graphs.

Comment: @xmh0511 Right, $y=f(t) = (t-1)^3$ and $y = g(t) = g(t-1+1) = (t-1)^3$ have the same graphs.

Comment: @peterwhy Thanks. However, `g(x+1)` can be simply transformed to `g(x) = (x-1)^3` as long as let `x = x-1`, why does the transformed `g(x)` now have the same graph as that of `f(x)`? Or, is it to say that the current `x` is different from the original `x` in `x+1`?

Comment: @xmh0511 $g(x+1)$ and $g(x)$ are two different functions, hence I asked for clarification in a previous comment. Putting $x=0$, $g(x+1) = g(0+1) = 0^3$ and so $y=g(x+1)$ passes through $(0,0)$; while $g(x) = g(0) = (0-1)^3$ and so $y=g(x)$ passes through $(0,-1)$.

Comment: @peterwhy Let me try to give my understanding. Within a coordinate system that has `t` as its horizontal axis, `y = g(t)`(or say y = g(t-1+1)) and `y = f(t)` are the same function and hence have the same graph. Within the coordinate system that has `x` as its horizontal axis, then `y = g(x+1)` and `y = f(x)` are not the same function, hence their graphs are different, instead, in this case, `g(x+1)` is simply the same as `g2(x) = x^3`. Is my understanding right?

Comment: @peterwhy By the definition in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_of_a_function#Definition), it says "Given a mapping f : X → Y , in other words a function `f` together with its domain `X` and codomain Y, the graph of the mapping is the set"  `G(f)={(x,f(x)):x∈X}`. In my example, it's `G(g){(t, g(t))}` for the graph of  `y = g(t)`, however, it we say x∈[0,6] for `g(x+1) = x^3`, obviously `t` must not be `t∈[0,6]`, instead, it should satisfy `0≤t-1≤6`.

Comment: @xmh0511 **1:** $g$ is one mapping; if we restrict its domain to $X=[0,6]$, then graph $G(g)=\{(t, g(t)): t\in [0,6]\}$ contains a pair $(0, g(0)) = (0, -1)$. **2:** A different mapping is $(x\mapsto g(x+1))$; if we restrict its domain to $[0,6]$, then graph $G(x\mapsto g(x+1)) = \{(t, g(t+1)): t\in[0,6]\}$ contains a pair $(0,g(0+1))=(0,g(1))= (0,0)$. To obtain the elements in graph 2, one would call $g$ with inputs from $[1,7]$ though.

Comment: @peterwhy In the first case, `g(0)` makes the `x` be `-1`, which is out of the range of `x`.

Comment: @xmh0511 True that for mapping **1**, if one wishes to obtain all $g(0)$ to $g(6)$, the only definition $g(x+1)=x^3$ has to accept every $x\in[-1, 5]$.

Comment: @peterwhy So, after understanding them, I think the compound function `g(x+1) = x^3` is a different function from `f(x) = (x-1)^3`. The compound function should be the same as `h(x) = x^3` and they have the same domain and codomain.

Comment: @xmh0511 Right, $y=f(x)=(x-1)^3$ and $y=g(x+1)=x^3$ have different graphs.

Comment: @peterwhy Ok. so, with =()=(−1)^3, =(+1)=^3 and =h()=^3, the latter two are equivalent, and the first is the right shift 1 unit of the third, right?